# Calling a class library that uses .net core - Error: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions

Tags: c#, dll, com, asp.net-core

I created a class library that references some .net core packages (like Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions).

This class library is meant to be used as a COM library. I'm able to build the dll and register the dll of my class library. I can then load the COM object. In a separate program. However, as soon as a call a function that uses a .net core class, I get the error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I can see the Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll next to MyApp.dll in the bin. Do I need to register all these dll's? I tried installing the .net core runtime (both x86 and x64 versions), but that didn't work.